# menu capability

Tags: android, menu

Is there any way to do a popup menu that is activated by a process within the program, such as the JPopupMenu class of Swing?  All I can find in the android literature is an options menu that can only be activated by pressing a menu button, and the context menu that can only be activated by a long press.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

Maybe this is also helpful: http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343